# How can i print the returned value of a method into the method of the same class

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public abstract class Astrodroid
{
    public virtual string GetSound()
    {
        return "Beep beep"; 
    }
    public void MakeSound()
    {
        //this method should print the returned value of above function
    }

}
```

In MakeSound method i have to print the value that is returned by the GetSound method.

Comment: You could use `this.GetSound()` to refer to method in the same object

Comment: What is the actual issue you are facing if you call GetSound from withing MakeSound function?

Comment: Show us how you will be using Astrodroid.

Comment: `public void MakeSound() { Console.WriteLine(GetSound()); }`

Answer (score 3):

You can call GetSound() from MakeSound. Here is an implementation.

```
class Program
{
    public abstract class Astrodroid
    {
        public virtual string GetSound()
        {
            return "Beep beep";
        }
        public void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetSound());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class MyClass:Astrodroid
    {

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.MakeSound();
    }
}
```